# How to get a clickable button to also activate upon a keypress? (Windows Form C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

I have a regular button called Btn_Down that activates when clicked, but I also want it to activate when the 'S' key is pressed. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to `KeyDown` event of form control which contains your button and add following code

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyData)
    {
        case Keys.S:
            button1_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            //Or
            //button1.PerformClick();
            break;
    }
}
```

Set form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`. These settings should give the effect you want.

---

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case 'S':
        case 's':
            button1_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            //Or
            //button1.PerformClick();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I have another question though. Originally I tried using KeyPress instead of KeyDown (I used KeyPressEventArgs and such, everything was right) and it worked for the few number keys I had (D1, D2, etc.) but for letter keys like Q and W, it only worked when I held shift. Do you know why this is?

Comment: `KeyPressEventArgs` provides `char` representation of a key. In `switch` statement uppercase and lowercase values must be checked. I don't know what you did but it is working for keys like Q and W. It also depents on current input language of keyboard.

Comment: I added code for `KeyPress` event. Sorry, I didn't pay attention when I first read your post.